# SetInterval - change interval when next minute reached

Tags: javascript

I have a timer that maintains an updated time on the page.

Here's the basics:

```
function startTimer() {
    setInterval(function () {
        updateTimer();
    }, 1000);
}
```

As you can see, the time is updated every second, however the time placeholder only shows hours and minutes, so the function is running 59 times too many every minute.

I've tried to make it so that it checks every second until the minute changes, then resets the interval from 1 second to 1 minute.

However, the new interval shows as updated but never kicks in (it still updates every second).

```
function startTimer() {
    var interval = 1000,
        d = new Date(),
        m = d.getMinutes();

    setInterval(function () {
        var d2 = new Date(),
            m2 = d2.getMinutes();

        if (m2 > m) interval = 60000;
        updateTimer();
        console.log(m + " => " + m2 + " => " + interval);
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: What does `updateTimer()` do?

Comment: It just updates a time on the page

Comment: `setInterval()` is only executed once. Changing the content of `interval` in the callback doesn't affect the already running interval.

Comment: @Andreas - is it doable, or is that set in stone?

Comment: `var myInterval = setInterval(function(){}, delay);` then `clearInterval(myInterval);` and then restart the interval with a new delay. If you want to change the delay for the interval this is a way to do it.

Comment: @JohnOhara you have to cancel this interval and set a new one. Although, I don't see a good reason to - just let it run every second - it's hardly an overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
function startTimer() {
    var interval = 1000,
        d = new Date(),
        m = d.getMinutes();

    setTimeout(function intervalHandler() {
        var d2 = new Date(),
            m2 = d2.getMinutes();

        if (m2 > m) interval = 60000;
        updateTimer();
        console.log(m + " => " + m2 + " => " + interval);
        setTimeout(intervalHandler, interval)
    }, interval);
}
```

Just use setTimeout instead setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another interval, you can't update the one that is already running, you can do something like this:

```
function startTimer() {
  var d = new Date(),
      m = d.getMinutes(),
      interval = 1000;
  var minutes;
  var seconds = setInterval(function () {
    var d2 = new Date(),
        m2 = d2.getMinutes();
    if (m2 > m) {
      //here we stop the first interval and we create another that runs every minute
      clearInterval(seconds)
      minutes = setInterval(updateTimer, 60000)
    };
    console.log(m + " => " + m2 + " => " + interval);
    }, interval); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By storing your interval and waiting period into their own variables out of the function scope you can make a comparison against the current wait time and the new one. this enables you to call the interval with one method and then reset it to another method at a later date.

```js
let wait_tracker = 0
let interval_tracker

const interval = (wait = 0, callback) => {  
  if (!callback) {
    clearInterval(interval_tracker)
    console.log('cancelling')
    return
  }

  if (wait !== wait_tracker && !!interval_tracker) clearInterval(interval_tracker)
  
  interval_tracker = setInterval(callback, wait)
}

interval(500, () => console.log('tick every .5sec'))
setTimeout(() => (
  interval(200, () => console.log('tick every .2sec'))
), 5000)

setTimeout(interval, 10000)
```

Another approach would be to return a Function out of the original `interval` Method, this will be your `destroy`  method as each time you create an `interval` the Closure is able to have it's own reference to it's `_INTERVAL` variable. See below how i have an Array of interval calls and then 10 seonds later i call destroy on all of them. This allows me to have multiple intervals set but gives me the controll to destroy them if i wish.

```js
const interval = (wait = 0, callback) => {  
  const _INTERVAL = setInterval(callback, wait)
  
  return () => {
    console.log('destroying')
    clearInterval(_INTERVAL)
  }
}
const intervals = [
  interval(500, () => console.log('tick every .5sec')),
  interval(200, () => console.log('tick every .2sec'))
]

setTimeout(() => intervals.forEach(destroy => destroy()), 10000)
```